# Problem with get_chirps() function from the package chirps in R

Tags: r

I am having problems with get_chirps() function from the package chirps in R.
When a use the funtion at any pair of lat/lon coordinates, I get only -9999 values.
This is the code I use, with one pair of coordinates example:

```
library(chirps)

lonlat <- data.frame(lon = -67.5, lat = -24.5)
dates <- c("1981-01-02", "2020-12-31")
data <- get_chirps(lonlat, dates)
```

I will appreciate any help on the issue.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. If you run the examples in the vignette and help file, these also give -9999 values, which they should not. I wonder if there is a problem with the server accessed by the package. Perhaps one for the package developers?

Comment: Actually, going through the debugger, the server is returning a huge json file in the correct format. It genuinely has all the rainfall values set to -9999. I don't know why, but it's not a bug on the R side - there's something wrong server-side.

Comment: And we're not in the Atacama?

Answer (score 0):

The API developers changed how the API works. We fixed the issue and it is working fine. You should also be able to change the data provider using the argument server.

```
library("chirps")

lonlat <- data.frame(lon = -67.5, lat = -24.5)
dates <- c("1981-01-02", "2020-12-31")
data <- get_chirps(lonlat, dates, server = "ClimateSERV")

data
```

I recommend this one when you deal with multiple points (>500) and dates at the same time

```
lonlat <- data.frame(lon = -67.5, lat = -24.5)
dates <- c("1981-01-02", "1981-01-04")
data <- get_chirps(lonlat, dates, server = "CHC")

data
```